# Definition of a Smooth Manifold

Tags: smooth-manifolds

I know that a smooth manifold is a topological manifold whose transition maps are smooth.

Must the coordinate maps also be smooth?  Must they be diffeomorphisms?

[MathWorld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CoordinateChart.html) seems to think so, but I do not understand why it follows from the definition that this must be the case.

Comment: What does it mean for a coordinate map to be smooth?

Comment: I'm not sure, I guess this might be the problem.

Comment: Right. There's no intrinsic notion of a derivative of a function on a manifold without resorting to coordinate maps.  So we say a map between manifolds $f:M\rightarrow N$ is smooth if the map gotten by pre and post composing f with coordinate maps is smooth.  The latter is a map between Euclidean spaces, where the notion of smoothness is familiar. So it's sort of tautological that coordinate maps are smooth because if you pre and post compose them with a coordinate map, taking the former coordinate map in both cases, you get the identity, which is certainly smooth.

Comment: To see that it follows from the definition, make sure you're looking at the relevant definition, not the definition of "smooth manifold" but the definition of "smooth map on a manifold".

Comment: I see now, thanks guys.